# Ubuntu Live CD boots to black screen, R9 290x

Tags: video, msi

I'm having problem to install the Ubuntu, I have a video card R9 290x MSI.
When I boot from USB, it shows all the choices, "Try Ubuntu, Install Ubuntu, Check disk", but when I choose one of this, the screen got black, and don't show anything at the screen. I tried to install in a VM, and works very well. I really don't know what is happening when I try to install Ubuntu.